# How to talk to geoclue through its dbus interface?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, d-bus

I'm trying to better understand what `geoclue` does, and how to gain information from it.

From my understanding, it can be accessed through it's `dbus` interface to find geographic information about the user. The problem is finding the right `dbus` command to gain this information.

I've searched all over the internet and checked all the documentation I could find, but still can't seem to find an easy answer other than obscure information about it's `dbus` properties, which I lack the knowledge to properly piece together.

Is there a `dbus` command I could use to gain this information from `geoclue`, and perhaps an example of what that command should look like? I do not have the information required to put together the documentation from it to gain this.

Answer (score 4):

Install `qdbus`. The syntax is:

```
qdbus servicename path function parameters
```

`servicename` is usually the name of a program (eg: org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Master), `path` is something like `/org/freedesktop/Geoclue/Master/client0`, `function` looks like org.freedesktop.Geoclue.GetStatus.

If you type an incomplete command (eg: only `servicename`, and not `path` and the rest), `qdbus` will reply with a list of options for the next argument. You can use this to explore the available functionality.

For example:

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.UbuntuGeoIP /org/freedesktop/Geoclue/Providers/UbuntuGeoIP org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Position.GetPosition
```

outputs:

```
3
<timestamp>
<lat>
<lon>
<alt>
```

Now you can use the [documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/geoclue/docs/index.html) for more information.